# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: sql

```
insert into product (CategoriesId) values (2) where Categories=' ab '
```

error is

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

i cannot understand please help me

Comment: is this sql? you cannot have a 'where' clause when inserting something...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you are interested in `UPDATE product SET CategoriesId =2 where Categories=' ab '`, insert is for a new row hence not sure why you would need a `where`

Comment: V4Vendetta update is perfectly working thanks

Comment: @Chips_100 By the way: You can have a `WHERE` if you use `INSERT` in comination with `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterRader, you are right - i considered the `insert into (...) values (...)`, in which `where` is not allowed (nor would it make sense, i guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to update the username or in the main while you are not inserting the record. so use update query instead of insert query and for insert query  Where clause is not used. Try this you can get your ans.. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

You can not have a where statement on the insert. If you are using a table then you can.

```
INSERT INTO product (CategoriesId) values (2)
```

Or like this:

```
INSERT INTO product (CategoriesId)
SELECT CategoriesId
FROM someTable
WHERE someTable.Categories=' ab '
```

Or if you have existing rows and want to `UPDATE` them. Then do this:

```
UPDATE product SET CategoriesId=2 WHERE Categories='ab'
```

Comment: you know if you are fine with the answer. You might consider accepting it

Answer (score 5):

You can not use where clause with insert , You should use update like this

```
update product set CategoriesId = 2 where Categories='ab'
```